# JQuery named functions with scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to execute a single function on a set of adjacent DIVS on my page. I thought it would work best like this:

```
function namedFunction(){
   setTimeout(3000);
   //do animations and such
   $(this).next().call(namedFunction);

}

$("#firstdiv").call(namedFunction());
```

but I can't find a way to arbitrarily execute a function in a set scope (the firstdiv object), and moreover I'm not even sure if the scope will be passed correctly. Is there a way to do this, or a better way to do this?

Comment: When are you expecting to call it? When the document loads? On a user action? I've never arbitrarily called any function before. I normally have a reason.

Comment: Yo, are you GNU Linux fan mate `:)` you have written recursive function in a pseudo manner i.e. calling same function within the function, just thought I will mention. `:)`

Comment: `setTimeout(3000)` will do nothing at all

Comment: @Yatrix, when the document loads I want to call the function on the first div. Then the first div would execute the function on it's next div and place itself at the end of the divs, so that the function continues forever (I'm displaying sliding panels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want this:

```
function namedFunction () {
   this.animate({ ... }, function () {
       namedFunction.call( $( this ).next() );
   });    
}
```

and then:

```
namedFunction.call( $('#firstdiv') );
```

Comment: that's it, that works perfectly, Thank you. I'm not quite sure I follow what's happening though, is the first argument when 'call' is called on a JS function assigned to the 'this' variable?

Comment: @user1681515 Yes. The `.call()` method is only available on native functions, and is used to explicitly define the `this` value of the invocation. So, `f()`, and `f.call(x)`, are both invoking the function `f`, but the latter is also defining the `this` value of that function call.

Comment: _"only available on native functions"_ - What do you mean by "native"?

Comment: @nnnnnn The standard defines the term ["native object"](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.6). In simple terms, a native function is a function what inherits from `Function.prototype`. Therefore, a native function is guaranteed to have a `.call()` method. Non-native functions are not guaranteed to have this method.

Answer (score 0):

The `setTimeout()` function doesn't pause the current execution, it queues a future execution of a function that you supply. To do something when the page loads use a document ready handler.

I think you want something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $divs = $("div.commonClass"),
        i = 0;
    function processNextDiv() {
        namedFunction($divs.eq(i));
        i = (i + 1) % $divs.length;
        setTimeout(processNextDiv, 3000);
    }
    processNextDiv();
});
```

This first selects all the divs (I'd suggest doing so by giving them a common class, but you can do that any way you like), then sets up a timeout based loop that calls `namedFunction()` passing it the current div to be processed. So then you could have:

```
function namedFunction($div) {
    $div.animate(...); // process current div
}
```

Or you could put the animation or other div processing code directly in that `processNextDiv()` function, depending on whether you want to be able to call `namedFunction()` from other places.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hWLTb/

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this?

```
$("#firstdiv").nextAll("div").andSelf().each(function(){
    // this = DIV
});
```